# Override application properties in Spring Boot integration tests

Tags: spring-boot, spring-test

I'm preparing a Spring Boot starter (used in tests) and I want to override a specific application property. This particular case regards enabling / disabling cache based on a property (production-code starter uses `@ConditionalOnProperty`). When using the test starter I want to have the caching disabled by default.

Is there a way to do that except using `@TestPropertySource`? Hence it is not a repeatable annotation, I don't want to use it. It's a recommended way for end-user to add properties required for the test case.

*Edit:*
I'm providing more details on the specific use case

Production Starter auto-configuration:

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnWebApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties(StarterCacheProperties.class)
@EnableCaching
public class StarterCacheAutoConfiguration {

..(omitted for clarity)..

@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "neostarter.saasmgr.cache", name = "enabled", havingValue = "false")
public static class SaasMgrNoCacheConfig extends CachingConfigurerSupport {

    @Bean(name = SAAS_MGR_CACHE_MANAGER)
    @Override
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        return new NoOpCacheManager();
    }
}

@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "neostarter.saasmgr.cache", name = "enabled", matchIfMissing = true)
public static class SaasMgrCachingConfig extends CachingConfigurerSupport {

    @Autowired
    SaasMgrCacheProperties saasMgrCacheProperties;

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
    public net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager ehCacheManager() {
        CacheConfiguration cacheConfiguration = new CacheConfiguration(SAAS_MGR_AUTH_CACHE, 1000)
                .timeToLiveSeconds(saasMgrCacheProperties.getTimeToLiveSeconds());

        net.sf.ehcache.config.Configuration config = new net.sf.ehcache.config.Configuration();
        config.addCache(cacheConfiguration);

        return net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.newInstance(config);
    }

    @Bean(name = SAAS_MGR_CACHE_MANAGER)
    @Override
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        return new EhCacheCacheManager(ehCacheManager());
    }
}
```

This gives user a choice of caching particular calls in production (or not). However, I find it reasonable to disable caching in tests by default. I am fully aware that this can still be overridden by end-user. In a test starter (different dependency) I tried the following:

```
@Configuration
@AutoConfigureBefore({CacheAutoConfiguration.class, SaasMgrSecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
public class DisableCacheAutoConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    Environment environment;

    @PostConstruct
    public void disableCache() {
        EnvironmentTestUtils.addEnvironment((ConfigurableEnvironment)environment, "neostarter.saasmgr.cache.enabled=false");
    }
}
```

but no matter what `StarterCacheAutoConfiguration` with `EhCacheCacheManager` is always resolved before `DisableCacheAutoConfiguration`. In debug in [AutoConfigurationSorter.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/44ddfcc7fae70e77162e6f3be10294ba7fded7fe/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/AutoConfigurationSorter.java#L70) I see proper order of the configuration:

```
15 = "com.neoteric.starter.auth.saasmgr.test.DisableCacheAutoConfiguration"
16 = "com.neoteric.starter.auth.SaasMgrSecurityAutoConfiguration"
36 = "org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration"
```

Comment: Maybe I am missing something it this conversation, but why can't you set up `spring.cache.type=none` as Stephane Nicoll is suggesting in `src/test/properties/application.properties`? That would be loaded by default during testing.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change user's configuration in a starter, that would be way too opaque and invasive. You have no guarantee about it anyway: anybody could set the property value at a higher level (e.g. system property) and override what you're trying to change.

If you want to disable caching, the most easiest  way to do it is to do what `spring.cache.type=none` does, that is providing an implementation of `CacheManager` that does not do anything.

Try to declare a bean of type `org.springframework.cache.support.NoOpCacheManager`

Comment: I don't want to force a property no matter what. Let's say I want to go in the middle. I have added more details about the specific use case I have. In a production starter I check a property to enable / disable caching. But when using test starter I want to disable caching in tests by default, but still letting end-user to use caching mechanism if he wants to (by @TestPropertySource or System property etc.)

Comment: My answer still stands IMO. I don't think that's very clear that an auto-configuration alters another configuration via the environment. Make sure that your custom auto-configuration has `@AutoconfigureBefore(CacheAutoConfiguration.class)`

Comment: My assumption is that end-user would be forced to disable this cache in almost every integration test. Hence, when explicitly stating that using this test starter implies disabling caching by default, I don't find this confusing.
Going back to the solution please see another edit. Despite having ordered class names looking correct it still loads EhCacheManager beforehand.

Comment: We can agree to disagree. This thread will end-up in debugging your code in comments which is not the right place for that stuff. Gitter maybe? There's no `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` on your ehcache config.